# Escape hyphen in PHP /mySQL query

Tags: php

The following line throws an error:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO mail_senders(mailAddress) VALUES ('$_POST[sender-email]')";
```

and the problem is the hyphen "-"

I might easily change "-" with "_" but I would like to know if it possible to escape that character for future reference.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent SQL injection you should escape your input. Then use sprintf for readability and use quotes for the index of the array. If you don't use quotes PHP sees sender-email as undefined constant and assumes that you actually mean the string "sender-email". If at some point you define sender-email your code will probably break.

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO mail_senders(mailAddress) VALUES ('%s')", mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["sender-email"]));
```

Comment: Brilliant! Actually I knew I had to escape the string despite I have both a Javascript and PHP input validation before inserting any data in the db to avoid any problem... your solution with just one line is perfect ;)

Answer (score 0):

Should be `$_POST['sender-email']`

```
$query = "INSERT INTO mail_senders(mailAddress) VALUES ('{$_POST['sender-email']}')";
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as your code stands, you're vulnerable to SQL injection - you should really look at parameterized queries.

Without being sure of the kind of database you're using, I'll write this using [Mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php):

```
$dbUser = 'username';
$dbPass = 'password';
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbName = 'databasename';

$dbConnection = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUser,$dbPass,$dbHost); 

$query = "INSERT INTO mail_senders (mailAddress) VALUES (?)";
if ($statement = $dbConnection->prepare($query)) {
    $statement->bind_param('s',$_POST['sender-email']);
    $statement->execute();

    //If this was a select statement, do stuff with result set here...
    ...
    ...
    ...

    //As this is an insert, you'll probably want to know if you've successfully inserted a row so...
    if ($statement->affected_rows > 0) {
        //Snip - update successful.
    }
  
    //And then close the connection
    $statement->close();
}
```

For more info on prepared statements with mysqli, look at [the mysqli prepare documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).